# user edit his question after being answered

Tags: discussion

I've answered a user question and my answer solved his issue, then he faced another issue so he edit the question to fit this 2nd issue, is this allowed ?

**[the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36678057/jenkins-error-fetching-remote-repo-origin/36681595#36681595)**

Comment: No, it's frowned upon editing questions to make existing answers invalid. But there's a good chance the question was unclear from the beginning, and you shouldn't have answered it at all. Impossible to tell without seeing the concrete example.

Comment: Yeah, they do that.  That, and many other annoying things.   Chameleon questions, homework-vamps deleting upon getting answers, wasting contributors' time on cmpetition entries, using SO as a dupllicate/Google slave etc, This is normal, daily SO abuse.  Get used to it.